# why does it not give the result of the currency? (is currency conversion)

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Divisas</title>
</head>
<body> 


<div class="contenedor" > 
          <form  action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"
            method="post">
            


            <select name="origen" id="origen" > 
          <option value="Divisas" <?php if($_POST['destino']=="Divisas")echo'selected="selected"';?>>Divisas</option>   
          <option value="Pesos" <?php if($_POST['origen']=="Pesos")echo'selected="selected"';?>>Pesos</option> 
          <option value="Dolar" <?php if($_POST['origen']=="Dolar")echo'selected="selected"';?>>Dolar</option> 
          <option value="Euros" <?php if($_POST['origen']=="Euros")echo'selected="selected"';?>>Euros</option> 
          <option value="Libras" <?php if($_POST['origen']=="Libras")echo'selected="selected"';?>>Libras</option> 
            </select> <br>
           
           <input type="number" name="formulario" name="dinero" placeholder="Cantidad" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['dinero'])){echo$_POST['dinero'];} ?>"> <br>
         
           <select name="destino" > 
          <option value="Divisas" <?php if($_POST['destino']=="Divisas")echo'selected="selected"';?>>Divisas</option> 
          <option value="Pesos" <?php if($_POST['destino']=="Pesos")echo'selected="selected"';?>>Pesos</option> 
          <option value="Dolar" <?php if($_POST['destino']=="Dolar")echo'selected="selected"';?>>Dolar</option> 
          <option value="Euros" <?php if($_POST['destino']=="Euros")echo'selected="selected"';?>>Euros</option> 
          <option value="Libras" <?php if($_POST['destino']=="Libras")echo'selected="selected"';?>>Libras</option> 
            </select> <br>

         <?php 
            error_reporting(0);
           $origen=htmlspecialchars($_POST['origen']);
           $destino=htmlspecialchars($_POST['destino']);
           $cantidad=htmlspecialchars($_POST['dinero']);
           $resul="";


          $post=(isset($_POST['origen']))&&!empty($_POST['origen'])
          &&(isset($_POST['destino']))&&!empty($_POST['destino'])
          &&(isset($_POST['dinero']))&&!empty($_POST['dinero']);


          if ($origen=="Pesos"&& $destino=="Pesos") {
            $resul=$cantidad;
          }elseif ($origen=="Pesos" && $destino=="Dolar") {
            $resul=$cantidad/20;
          }elseif ($origen=="Pesos" && $destino=="Euros") {
            $resul=$cantidad/23;
          }elseif ($origen=="Pesos" && $destino=="Libras") {
            $resul=$cantidad/27;
          }




        ?>

      <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cambio" placeholder="Tipo" value="<?$resul?>" > <br>

      <input type="submit" name="calcular" class="btn btn-cal" value="Calcular"><br>


 </body>

</html>
```

I have to make a currency conversion, but when I run it, the action is not done, and I can't find the error.

Comment: try with `value="<?=$resul?>"`

Comment: "can't find the error" — With `error_reporting(0)` you're literally asking PHP: "hide error messages, if any".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know.. i tried to solve it like that :

```php
<?php
$conv = ['Pesos' => 1, 'Dolar' => 20.08 , 'Euros' => 22.07, 'Libra' => 26.31];
$value = isset($_POST['dinero']) ? (float) $_POST['dinero'] : null ;
$origen = isset($_POST['origen']) && is_string($_POST['origen']) ? $_POST['origen'] : null ;
$destino = isset($_POST['destino']) && is_string($_POST['destino']) ? $_POST['destino'] : null ;
if (isset($conv[$origen], $conv[$destino]))
    $resul = $value * $conv[$origen] / $conv[$destino] ;
else
    $resul = null ;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Divisas</title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="contenedor"> 
            <form  action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
            <select name="origen" id="origen"> 
                <option>Divisas</option>
                <?php
                    foreach($conv as $k => $v)
                    {
                    echo '<option';
                    if ($origen == $k)
                    echo ' selected';
                    echo '>', $k, '</option>';
                    }
                ?>          
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="number" name="dinero" placeholder="Cantidad" value="<?= isset($value) ? $value : '' ?>"> <br>
            <select name="destino" id="destino"> 
                <option>Divisas</option>
                <?php
                    foreach($conv as $k => $v)
                    {
                    echo '<option';
                    if ($destino == $k)
                    echo ' selected';
                    echo '>', $k, '</option>';
                    }
                ?>          
            </select>
            <br>
            <?php

            ?>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="cambio" placeholder="Tipo" value="<?= isset($resul) ? number_format($resul, 2, '.', '') : '' ?>" >
                <br>
                <input type="submit" name="calcular" class="btn btn-cal" value="Calcular">
                <br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```